# AWS SDK PHP iterator

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I've written a small function (in PHP) to return all AWS instances in my account. 
I've tried using the basic describe instances method but it times out (see below).

So the new function uses the getIterator, however, the page still times out. If it set the max results to 10 it works, but I think that defeats the object. I want a full list of all of my instances.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong that would cause my request to time out? The time out message I get is:

> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

```
        public function allInstances(){

        $response = $this->ec2Client->getIterator('describeInstances',array(
            'Filters' => array(
                array(

                    'Name' => 'instance-state-name',
                    'Values' => array('running')

                    )

                ))
            );

        return $response;

    }
```

> Update to original post:

This is my code for iterating through the results return by the describeInstances itertator. I know I have around 400 instances running, however the result never returns anything more than about 280.

```
foreach($iterator as $object){

   $value = $object['Reservation'];

   //echo "<pre>" . print_r($object,true) . "</pre>"; 

   $number = $count++;

   echo $count . ">" .  "<b>InstanceID: </b>" . $object['InstanceId'] . " <b>AMI: </b>" . $object['ImageId'] . "</br>";

}
```